# What double struck font is this?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, blackboard

there is a double struck font in an old book I own that I really like, but no font searching machine did find any usable or correct results.

The book is from the early 90s and it is already TeXed, so I hope the there used font is still around, but I have no Idea where to look.

It is not included in `mathalfa` or other math alphabet collections.

Here is a picture of one letter:

[image: Double struck symbol for the real numbers]

And here is a link to the google books page of the book itself:

https://books.google.de/books?id=PUygBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA194&hl=de&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: That looks like `I\!R` to me, that is two separate characters, bunched together. That was the common way to produce this symbol before the AMS fonts came out.

Comment: The dsfont package create characters similar to this, but they are not exactly the same. `\mathds{R}`

Comment: Thanks Alain! I really like the font you brought up, I'm going to use this - David suggestion looks exactly like the printed letters, so they seem to be tinkered then, right?

Comment: @Student The ams blackboard bold font was only just available (or not available) around that time and tex usage (and tex users) being what it is the IR combination was in common use for years (and it's still not that uncommon to see it now:-)

Answer (score 5):

That looks like `I\!R` to me, that is two separate characters, bunched together. That was the common way to produce this symbol before the AMS fonts came out

Answer (score 0):

Your Image is a solution like David's answer. Here is an up-to-date one.
Run with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}

$\BbbR^n$

\end{document}
```

[image]